# What are the use cases to substitute cookbook array attribute in chef?

Tags: chef-infra

Suppose I should setup `unattended_upgrades` within latest `apt=6.1.4` cookbook.

I use following role for that:

```
{                                                                                                                                                     
  "name": "default_base",
  "description": "Role applied to all workstations and servers",
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "default_attributes": {
    "apt": {
      "unattended_upgrades" : { 
        "enable": "true",
        "allowed_origins" : [
          "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security"
        ], 
        "mail": "ops@example.com"
      }   
    }
}
```

But the final part of config looks like:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "Ubuntu xenial";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
};
```

`Ubuntu xenial` is a array element defined in apt cookbook `attributes/default.rb file. And it's merged with role attribute as described in doc. This is because it is array.

I found only one workaround - is a reset that attribute in `default_attributes` section in `default_base` role. Like follows:

```
"default_attributes": {
  "apt": {
    "unattended_upgrades" : {
      "allowed_origins" : []
    }
  }
}
```

As a result, the resulting role contains same attribute declaration in same role, but in different precedence levels.

What is this?

`Common use case | Good solution | Dirty hack | Unskillful engineer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant the second of those to be `override_attributes`, which is a workaround for this. Unfortunately the mechanics of array merging in attributes is very tricky and dependent on a lot Chef internals, so that's probably the easiest option.